# PG::Coder.new(hash) is deprecated. Please use keyword arguments instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Since updating to pg 1.5.2, we are seeing this warning in console all the time, coming from `.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:980:in 'new'.`

Ruby 3.2.2, Rails 7.0.4.3

I did not find much on google, does anyone know how to fix it?

```rb
def update_typemap_for_default_timezone
  if @default_timezone != ActiveRecord.default_timezone && @timestamp_decoder
    decoder_class = ActiveRecord.default_timezone == :utc ?
      PG:: TextDecoder::TimestampUtc :
      PG: :TextDecoder::TimestampWithoutTimeZone

    @timestamp_decoder = decoder_class. new(@timestamp_decoder. to_h)
    @connection.type_map_for_results.add_coder (@timestamp_decoder)

    @default_timezone = ActiveRecord.default_timezone

    # if default timezone has changed, we need to reconfigure the connection
    # (specifically, the session time zone)
    configure_connection
  end
end
```

I googled and I did not find anything

Comment: Please post code as formatted text, not images. The error literally says what to do.

Comment: That code is part of rails itself, since I'm not a Rails contrib I can't fix it. Anyways, it's already fixed and merged, I'm leaving this post just because it's easier to find it via Google

Answer (score 8):

Right after posting this I found my answer, but it can be helpful for someone else

Issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48046
PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48048

Already merged and will be released in new patch version. Remember to update folks!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to upgrade from Rails 7.0.4 to 7.0.6 (and the associated postgres_adapter) to see that warning go away.

Upgrading PG wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stuck on Rails 6.1.x, this won't get fixed, as Rails 6.1 only receives security fixes.

But if you still want to get rid of this warning, there is a way. As you can see in this (closed) [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48435), the fix is simply:

```
- @timestamp_decoder = decoder_class.new(@timestamp_decoder.to_h)
+ @timestamp_decoder = decoder_class.new(**@timestamp_decoder.to_h)
```

on line 883 of `activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb`

Depending on where you are seeing this warning, you can monkeypatch the method in Rails, by creating a `my_monkeypatch.rb` file in `config/initializers` and adding:

```rb
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class PostgreSQLAdapter < AbstractAdapter
      def update_typemap_for_default_timezone
        if @default_timezone != ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone && @timestamp_decoder
          decoder_class = ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone == :utc ?
            PG::TextDecoder::TimestampUtc :
            PG::TextDecoder::TimestampWithoutTimeZone

          @timestamp_decoder = decoder_class.new(**@timestamp_decoder.to_h)
          @connection.type_map_for_results.add_coder(@timestamp_decoder)
          @default_timezone = ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To have the changes picked up, I needed to run `bin/spring stop`.

I was seeing this warning in my tests, so I also needed to require the monkeypatch file from `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
require_relative '../config/initializers/my_monkeypatch.rb'
```

Comment: I added a `raise "Remove this now" if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 7` bomb to make sure it gets removed as part of a future Rails upgrade

Comment: That's a nice touch!